# How to convert this UIGraphics image operation to Core Image?

Tags: swift, image-processing, core-image, imagefilter

I write **SplitMirror** filter like in Apple Motion app or Snapchat lenses by using `UIGraphics` to use it with real time camera feed or video processing, with single image request it works well like in attached image in the question but for multiple filtering request not. I think it's code must be changed from `UIGraphics` to `Core Image & CIContext` for better performance and less memory usage like `CIFilters` and actually I don't know how to do it.
I tried several ways to convert it but I stuck on merging left and right, this can be done with `CICategoryCompositeOperations filters but which one is fit this case I o have idea, so need some help with this issue.

Filter code using `UIGraphics`:

```
//
//  SplitMirror filter.swift
//  Image Editor
// 
//  Created by Coder ACJHP on 25.02.2022.
// 
// SnapChat & Tiktok & Motion App like image filter
// Inspired from 'https://support.apple.com/tr-tr/guide/motion/motn169f94ea/mac'
// Splits an image in half vertically and reverses the left remaining half to create a reflection.

final func splitMirrorFilter(processingImage image: UIImage) -> UIImage {
    // Image size
    let imageSize = image.size

    // Left half
    let leftHalfRect = CGRect(
        origin: .zero,
        size: CGSize(
                width: imageSize.width/2,
                height: imageSize.height
                )
    )
    
    // Right half
    let rightHalfRect = CGRect(
        origin: CGPoint(
            x: imageSize.width - (imageSize.width/2).rounded(),
            y: 0
        ),
        size: CGSize(
            width: imageSize.width - (imageSize.width/2).rounded(),
            height: imageSize.height
        )
    )
    // Split image into two parts
    guard let cgRightHalf = image.cgImage?.cropping(to: rightHalfRect) else { return image }
    // Flip right side to be used as left side
    let flippedLeft = UIImage(cgImage: cgRightHalf, scale: image.scale, orientation: .upMirrored)
    let unFlippedRight = UIImage(cgImage: cgRightHalf, scale: image.scale, orientation: image.imageOrientation)
    
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(imageSize, false, image.scale)
    
    flippedLeft.draw(at: leftHalfRect.origin)
    unFlippedRight.draw(at: rightHalfRect.origin)
    
    guard let splitMirroredImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext() else { return image }
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    return splitMirroredImage
}
```

[image: It's result looks like]

Here is what it tried with `Core Image`

```
    // Splits an image in half vertically and reverses the left remaining half to create a reflection.
final func splitMirrorFilterCIImageVersion(processingImage image: UIImage) -> CIImage? {

    
    guard let ciImageCopy = CIImage(image: image) else { return image.ciImage }
    
    // Image size
    let imageSize = ciImageCopy.extent.size
    let imageRect = CGRect(origin: .zero, size: imageSize)

    // Left half
    let leftHalfRect = CGRect(
        origin: .zero,
        size: CGSize(
                width: imageSize.width/2,
                height: imageSize.height
                )
    )
    
    // Right half
    let rightHalfRect = CGRect(
        origin: CGPoint(
            x: imageSize.width - (imageSize.width/2).rounded(),
            y: 0
        ),
        size: CGSize(
            width: imageSize.width - (imageSize.width/2).rounded(),
            height: imageSize.height
        )
    )
    
    
    
    // Split image into two parts
    let cgRightHalf = ciImageCopy.cropped(to: rightHalfRect)
    context.draw(cgRightHalf.oriented(.upMirrored), in: leftHalfRect, from: imageRect)
    context.draw(cgRightHalf, in: rightHalfRect, from: imageRect)
    
    // I'm stuck here
    
    // Merge two images into one 
    // Here I don't know which filter can be used to merge op
    // CICategoryCompositeOperation filters may fits
}
```

Comment: Entire code shared [here](https://gist.github.com/Coder-ACJHP/571eac3da8b3d3437116e1353602d5fa)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are on the right track.

You can create the left half from the right half by applying transformations to it using `let leftHalf = rightHalf.transformed(by: transformation)`. The transformation should mirror it *and* translate it to the correct position, i.e., next to the right half.

You can them combine the two into one image using `let result = leftHalf.composited(over: rightHalf)` and render that result using a `CIContext`.

Comment: This is the right way, + also my mind was confused because of long time working on videos and now I remember I don't need to render it :) Let me write the code and share it here.

Answer (score 0):

After getting the correct idea from **Frank Schlegel** 's answer I rewrote filter code and now works well.

```
 // Splits an image in half vertically and reverses the left remaining half to create a reflection.
final func splitMirrorFilterCIImageVersion(processingImage image: UIImage) -> CIImage? {
    
    guard let ciImageCopy = CIImage(image: image) else { return image.ciImage }
    
    // Image size
    let imageSize = ciImageCopy.extent.size
    
    // Right half
    let rightHalfRect = CGRect(
        origin: CGPoint(
            x: imageSize.width - (imageSize.width/2).rounded(),
            y: 0
        ),
        size: CGSize(
            width: imageSize.width - (imageSize.width/2).rounded(),
            height: imageSize.height
        )
    )
            
    // Split image into two parts
    let ciRightHalf = ciImageCopy.cropped(to: rightHalfRect)
    // Make transform to move right part to left
    let transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: -rightHalfRect.size.width, y: -rightHalfRect.origin.y)
    // Create left part and apply transform then flip it
    let ciLeftHalf = ciRightHalf.transformed(by: transform).oriented(.upMirrored)
            
    // Merge two images into one
    return ciLeftHalf.composited(over: ciRightHalf)
}
```